# What does "Classified shots" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching TV Show The equalizer and One character who is a sniper says about how she shot people with her rifle in war and saying "hard shots. classified shots. 17 confirmed kills". I guessed "hard shot" as "she shot the real person". but I can't even guess what classified shot means. classified as good? or classified as secret? unofficial?

Comment: "hard" probably just means "difficult", no?

Comment: Oh, yeah. I thought it as something like "hard copy". but it seems like "difficult", now.

Answer (score 2):

Simple really - some of the 'work' done by a sniper is clandestine, dependant on secret intelligence, or to use the military parlance: "classified".

Technically, "classified" is the lowest rating of secrecy, but when a military person describes a situation as "classified" they mean that it is secret, that they are not allowed to talk about it.

Comment: I don't know whether things are different in your country, but for the U.S. government, "confidential" is the lowest level of classification.